# How to use sadd with multiple elements in Redis using Python API?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

Please consider the following example

```
>>import redis
>>redis_db_url = '127.0.0.1'
>>r = redis.StrictRedis(host = redis_db_url,port = 6379,db = 0)
>>r.sadd('a',1)
>>r.sadd('a',2)
>>r.sadd('a',3)
>>r.smembers('a')
```

[+] output: set(['1', '3', '2'])

```
>>r.sadd('a',set([3,4]))
>>r.smembers('a')
```

[+] output: set(['1', '3', '2', 'set([3, 4])'])

```
 >>r.sadd('a',[3,4])
 >>r.smember('a')
```

[+] set(['1', '[3, 4]', '3', '2', 'set([3, 4])'])

According to the official documentation in https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
    sadd(name, *values)
    Add value(s) to set name

So is it a bug or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you see the syntax `*values` in an argument list, it means the function takes a variable number of arguments.

Therefore, call it as

```
r.sadd('a', 1, 2, 3)
```

You can pass an iterable by using the splat operator to unpack it:

```
r.sadd('a', *set([3, 4]))
```

or

```
r.sadd('a', *[3, 4])
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but i don't think you have to cast as a `set` before unpacking

Comment: No, you don't, but I was following the example in the author's question. In this case the inline syntax is just a shortcut for indicating that you can do this with an arbitrary set (or indeed, an arbitrary iterable).

Comment: And really, on any recent Python you can just do `*{3, 4}` which is the native syntax for set literals, eliminating the "cast" altogether.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to clarify the point because I didn't want readers to think you had to cast to `set` for use in `sadd` or something. I'd recommend editing the answer to separate out the declaration of the iterable (set) in another line or just remove the casting all together.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
r.sadd('a', 1, 2, 3)
```

That should do the trick.