# How to sadd multiple elements with scala redisClient

Tags: scala, redis

now my code like this:

```
val elems  = List("1","2","3")
for(elem <- elems){
  redis.sadd("elems",elem)
}
```

is there any method to sadd multiple elements like python's api.

[How to use sadd with multiple elements in Redis using Python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035274/how-to-use-sadd-with-multiple-elements-in-redis-using-python-api)

I use https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through sources you can see that `sadd` is defined here https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/redis/SetOperations.scala as:

```
def sadd(key: Any, value: Any, values: Any*)(implicit format: Format): Option[Long] =
    send("SADD", List(key, value) ::: values.toList)(asLong)
```

This is good if you list elements manually i.e.

```
redis.sadd("elems", "1", "2", "3")
```

It is done to disallow using empty list. What you can do with this api is

```
val elems  = List("1","2","3")
redis.sadd("elems", elems.head, elems.tail: _*)
```

you could as well add a method that suits you to `RedisClient` class via implicit conversion

```
implicit class RichRedis(self: RedisClient) {
    def saddseq(key: Any, values: Seq[Any])(implicit format: Format): Option[Long] =
        self.sadd(key, values.head, values.tail: _*)
}
```

and then you could do:

```
val elems  = List("1","2","3")
redis.saddseq("elems", elems)
```

Note that you can't overload `sadd` it needs a different name.

Remember that you cannot call `head` on an empty list, so whenever you use this method with empty list you will get exception, which is reasonable considering that you can't add just a key.

Comment: I think you switched `sadd`/`saddseq` in you implicit class. It could also be worth mentioning that it'll raise an exception when `values` is empty.

Comment: Right I switched them, thank you. This will rise an exception, yes but I think this is what should happen. I think you can't add just a key without values, this is why original method prevented it. With workaround like this I think exception should be expected.

Comment: Yes, I don't think think there is any reasonable behavior here apart from throwing a exception. Just thought a `obviously, this will raise … so you might to handle that earlier in your code` mention might be useful.